# Out of Memory error when trying to connect to oracle database (VB6)

Tags: oracle, vb6

when I m trying to set Recordset using oracle connection string, I m getting OUt of memory error.

on line "**rsLIS.Open sql, gConnLIS, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly**"

However some time it works like once in 5-6 attempts

but when it works it gives error on some other line

on line "**If rsLink.Fields(2).value = rsLIS.Fields(1).value Then**"

here are the things which I tried :

1. instead of directly using recordset, I tried to create array (GetRows) method.

Even though recordset count is 26 but UBound of array is showing 1

2. I have trying changing 3rd argument value from static to forward only
   in line ""rsLIS.Open sql, gConnLIS, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly""

it also didn't work, it was showing recordset.count as 0

3. Did try after restarting the client system still same

I m getting this error on client side and since at my place I don't have development environment to debug

**Error is "OUT OF MEMORY"**

```
Public Function GetResults_New(MachName As String, patid As String, bCheckDate As Boolean, SendAssay As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset
On Error GoTo errdesc
Call ShowTempMsg("Line 1")
Dim bXVar As Boolean
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim tmplis, tmporder
Dim tmpresult

bXVar = False

Dim rec_result As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim rsLink As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsLIS As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim xSampleIdType As String

gAppPath = AddEditINIfile("VAHSIF.INI", "IF", "sLinkPath", "")
xSampleIdType = AddEditINIfile(gAppPath & "\sLinkConfig.ini", MachName, "SampleIdType", "SampleId1", False)

Call Open_Connection
Call Open_Connection_LIS
rec_result.CursorLocation = adUseClient


If SendAssay = True Then
    rec_result.Fields.Append "machineparamid", adBSTR, 50
    rec_result.Fields.Append "Assayno", adBSTR, 50
    rec_result.Fields.Append "SType", adBSTR, 50
    rec_result.Fields.Append "Dilution", adBSTR, 50
Else
    rec_result.Fields.Append "machineparamid", adBSTR, 50
    rec_result.Fields.Append "SType", adBSTR, 50
    rec_result.Fields.Append "Dilution", adBSTR, 50
End If

rec_result.Open
\
'Link Query For Mapped Params.
sql = "SELECT EquipParamMapping.EquipId, EquipParamMapping.EquipParamCode, EquipParamMapping.LISParamCode, EquipParamMapping.EquipAssayNo from EquipParam, EquipParamMapping where equipParam.equipid = equipparammapping.equipid and equipparam.equipparamcode = equipparammapping.equipparamcode and EquipParam.EquipID = '" & MachName & "' and EquipParam.isProgram = 'Y'"


**rsLink.Open sql, gConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly**



If enumConnTo = connOracle Then
    sql = "select " & xSampleIdType & " , LIS_Param_Code From SL_21CI_View_sampleid_Orders where " & xSampleIdType & " || SuffixCode = '" & patid & "'  and isApplicable <> 'N'  "
Else
    sql = "select " & xSampleIdType & " , LIS_Param_Code From SL_21CI_View_sampleid_Orders where " & xSampleIdType & " + cast(SuffixCode as varchar(20)) = '" & patid & "'  and isApplicable <> 'N' "
End If

rsLIS.Open sql, gConnLIS, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
 

While Not rsLIS.EOF
    
    If bXVar = True Then
        rsLink.MoveFirst
        bXVar = False
    End If
    While Not rsLink.EOF
    
        bXVar = True

  
        **If rsLink.Fields(2).value = rsLIS.Fields(1).value Then**
         
            If SendAssay = True Then
               
                rec_result.AddNew
        
                rec_result("machineparamid") = rsLink.Fields("EquipParamCode")
               
                rec_result("Assayno") = rsLink.Fields("EquipAssayNo")
               
                rec_result("SType") = " "
               
                rec_result("Dilution") = "0"
              
                
                rec_result.Update
               
                
                rec_result.MoveFirst
              
                
            Else
            
                rec_result.AddNew
                
                rec_result("machineparamid") = rsLink.Fields("EquipParamCode")
                rec_result("SType") = " "
                rec_result("Dilution") = "0"
                
                rec_result.Update
                
                rec_result.MoveFirst
            End If
            
            GoTo NextParam
        End If
     
        rsLink.MoveNext
    Wend
NextParam:
        rsLIS.MoveNext
Wend
    
Set GetResults_New = rec_result
    
Exit Function
errdesc:
    Call InsertIntoLogWithFileName("Transaction.GetResults_New" & vbNewLine & sql & vbNewLine & err.Description & "ErrLine : " & ErrLine)
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls reformat your post so that the all source code is properly formatted as such? Also: where (which line) does the error happen?

Comment: looks like now it is proper .. have a look now

Answer (score 1):

That still leaves the question on which line the error occurs. Also: "it also didn't work, it was showing recordset.count as 0". The RecordSet.Count property depends on the provider. Use a function similar to this instead:

```
Public Function RecordCount(ByVal cn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal sTable As String) As Long

  Dim sSQL As String, lRetVal as Long
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS RecCount FROM " & sTable & ";"
  Call rs.Open(sSQL, cn)

  If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    lRetVal = rs.Fields("RecCount").Value
  Else
    lRetVal = -1
  End If

  Call rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

  RecordCount = lRetVal

End Function
```

The `.Count` property might also very well be the cause of the Out of memory error, as I seem to remember that for determing the number of records, it loads all records (from the server) to count them. But I might be wrong there.

Comment: Error is on line "rsLIS.Open sql, gConnLIS, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly"

Comment: And sometime it works on above code after that error occurs on line "If rsLink.Fields(2).value = rsLIS.Fields(1).value Then"

Comment: Out of curiosity? How many records (i.e. data size) would that SQL statement return? You might really run out of memory. Sum up the memory used for column returned, multiply it with the amount of rows returned an see if that fits into RAM.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: try optimizing your WHERE close when using boolean operators. Put those conditions that weed out the most records from the possible result set FIRST in your WHERE clause. E.g. `isApplicable <> 'N'` might remove more records from the result set than that xSampleIdType construct. And judging from the column names and there actual values, there's also room for (memory) optimization, e.g. `patid` sounds like a numeric column, but is treated like a string, `isApplicable` sounds like a boolean values, but is also a string.

Comment: its returning 21 records.  can you please explain this line "Sum up the memory used for column returned, multiply it with the amount of rows returned an see if that fits into RAM". sorry I am just started learning so don't know much

Comment: 21 doesn't sound much. As for the meaning of that line: each [data type has a specific storage size](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-sql-server-data-types/), e.g. a Bit column is 1 byte. Sum up these for each column your query returns and multiply it by the number of rows = ?? KB/MB/GB memory needed on the server or client (CursorLocation) to handle the returned resulting recordset.

Comment: And if you just started learning, I suggest that you ask "How to" question, instead of "Why" questions. E.g. describe what you are trying to do (e.g. "compare 2 columns in 2 different databases") and post what approach (code) you used for now and what problem you've got. With knowing _what_ you are trying to achieve, people here will most likely come up with better and more elegant solutions to your problem than the one you currently use. But without knowing the actual goal of the operation, that's hard to do.